# How To Send Request To C# Method And Get Its Parameters by Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, api

Is there any way to call an API to know its required parameters?
for example, if there is a controller has a method takes a name and date as a parameters

```
[HttpPost]
 public string testUrl(string name,string date)
 {
    return "success";
 }
```

now what I am trying to do is to make a dynamic form take an API URL and generate all required inputs so I have to find some way to call the URL and return the required parameters.

Comment: If there is no Schema declared for this somewhere, or something like Open ApI ect. Then no, you cant magically know the schema of a remote webservice.

Comment: As above, but look in to using [Swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) instead to automatically create the API documentation for you

Comment: so how can I declare a Schema and make it return the parameters?

Comment: So.. you're saying you want to build a 'meta' API which returns data on the API itself when you call that API. Seems a bit redundant.

Comment: in this way, I have to declare it with every method I want some dynamically that I can make it work with any API is there any way to get the parameters by sent request or by the response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would be to just hard code it:

```
[HttpPost]
public string testUrl(string name,string date)
{
    return "success";
}

public APISchema TestUrlSchema(){
    return new APISchema() { 
        Parameters = new List<Parameter>(){
            new Parameter(){ Name = "name", Type = "String" },
            new Parameter(){ Name = "date", Type = "String" }
        }
    };    
}

public class APISchema  {
    public List<Parameter> Parameters {get;set;}
}

public class Parameter {
    public String Name {get;set;}
    public String Type {get;set;}
}
```

You could use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to auto-generate this if you want to do it for a large number of actions.

As comments have mentioned, there are libraries [Swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) which will do this for you.

Comment: is an APISchema is a class I have to declare it? or just to add a specific useing?

Comment: @SamaNoov - Yes that was just an example. See my edit for example definitions. Not sure exactly what information about the parameters you are wanting, figured name and type was a good start...